# What is the best way to learn a framework / module in python?

Tags: python, module, frameworks

Hey I am an Intermediate in python and I'm pretty comfortable with tackling any problem with python. But, I don't know what's the best way to learn how to use python modules or frameworks, like, PyGame, DJango, Flask, etc...

Can someone please suggest a way of learning a module quickly and efficiently.

Comment: A good starting point is to read the documentation.

Comment: @KlausD. Yeah, but django's docs tutorials are not that great in my opinion.

Comment: Ouch! I personally found Django docs to be one of the best ones out there!

Comment: @MartinMartynasMarkevičius So did I perceive the DJango docs in a wrong way. . I saw a tutorial section in that docs and went straight to it, but I was struck with that. Can you suggest what to make out of that docs please.

Comment: That's too unspecific. Please come up with a clear question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always found that the best way to learn a framework is by, well, using it. I know that's the most basic answer you can get, but getting stuck and reading documentation is the best way to learn something.

I also sometimes find myself `(ctrl|command) + Left Mouse Button` clicking through the source code of a library in VS Code just to get myself familiar with the library and how it's built. Also, calling `dir(module)` also gives some useful information about the module such as attributes and methods.

Comment: But DJango is particularly hard to do this, I tried to learn DJango by doing this and followed there tutorial, but I took just a tiny bit of information from that.

Comment: Try out multiple guides of multiple forms until you find the one that suits you the best! For instance, i personally cannot stand video tutorials, hence i always stick to written ones. Or, in general, other guides may be clearer than the ones you've seen, so don't give up! When it comes to Django, try to stand up a basic app/site and then progress from there with some more advanced concepts!

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't learn DJango because I was stuck with the DJango official docs. I'll try out other guides, too. Even I can't stand video tutorials.